# How do i query the database to grab each user post and count the number of post from the user?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a datatable, but I am having trouble querying the database. What I want to do is select one instance of each user on the datatable and I want to grab a count of all the products created by that user.

```
    Products Table
    id  user_id   title
    1      2       tv
    2      2       car
    3      2       book
    4      3       glasses

So user(2) has 3 products
So user(3) has 1 products
```

---

Here is the code I been working on

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
     ->join('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
     ->select('users.*', 'products.id', 'url')
     ->groupBy('products.id', 'url')
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the user details, together with a count of the products, grouped by the user id, as follows:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('users.*, COUNT(products.id) AS products')
    ->join('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thx and if i were to display the count how would i do that `{{$user->id->count}}` @fubar

Comment: If you `dd()` one of the results, you can see all of the column names. But in my query you'd use `$user->products`. Of course, this can be renamed to whatever you like by modifying the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really simply with eloquent

Say you have your User model and Product model.

In your database structure, for your products table, you need to include a column called user_id as an integer data type.

Then You declare this relationship on the user model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

then the inverse of the relation on the product's model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now you can simply do the following

```
//This returns all users with products (eager loading pointes out by fubar)
$users = User::with('products')->get();

//Now you could pass $users to your view and loop through like so
@foreach($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->name }} has {{ $user->products->count() }} </li>
@endforeach
```

for a specific user, you can simply

```
$user = User::find($id);
$userProductCount = $user->products->count();
```

eloquent really does make everything so clean and beautiful

Comment: Doing that in a `foreach` loop is really inefficient, as it will execute `n + 1` queries.

Comment: You can get as _"excited"_ as you like. I am merely pointing out that your code is a poor example, because it is still using `n + 1` queries.

Comment: Because you're not eager loading the `products` relation. So a separate query will be executed on every iteration of the `foreach` loop to retrieve the products. Also, your relation is called `products` and your code uses `product`.

Comment: yeah you are completely right, I forgot I had just done an all();
Thank you so much, you wonderful human. I am laid in my bed with my laptop on my chin so the typos are human error